# How to make button appear beside input text focused (Like 'Medium' create story)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make button appear like image shown below. Do you guys have advice?

Medium create story screenshot:

[image: Medium create story screenshot]

Comment: please write the code what have you tried.

Comment: Maybe you guys have any jquery plugins or something else to make 'This' happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try some css to achive your button style:

HTML :

`<span class="p-btn">+</span>`

CSS :

```
span.p-btn {
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

After span (button) you can add your text.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my.btn:focus,
.my.btn:hover,
.my.btn{

    background:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    color:gray;
    padding: 0px;
}

.myInput{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}
.myInput:focus{
    border: none; outline:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div>
<button class="my btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></button>
<input type="text" class="myInput">  
</div>
```